# How can I make an array of all of the instances of a class?

Tags: java, arrays, class, instance

I want to make an array of all the instances of a class, so that every time a new instance was made, it would automatically be added to the array. How would I do this?

Comment: You would put something in the constructor of the object to add it to the array you want them in.

Comment: First of all, arrays do not have dynamic size. They can not grow, they have fixed size. Maybe you want a `List` here. Anyways, you could have the list as static field and add the instance in its constructor, `instances.add(this);`. Note that this approach would effectively eliminate garbage collection as you hold instances alive. You could use `WeakReference`s instead. But honestly, this sounds like a **XY problem**. What are you trying to achieve with this? A cache? There are likely better approaches to what you want to achieve than this idea.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). Factory will be the only way to get new instances and therefore can save them in an array.

Comment: That is a very broad answer. You did not attempt to show OP how to do it. The pattern itself does not attempt to solve OPs issue directly.

Answer (score 1):

To show what `Zabuza` was talking about in an example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Example {

  private static ArrayList<Example> collection;

  public Example() {
    getCollection().add(this);
  }

  public static ArrayList<Example> getCollection() {
    if(collection == null)
      collection = new ArrayList<Example>();
    return collection;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi. I tried this, and got this error.
Example.java:18: error: -> expected
collection = new ArrayList<Example>();
                                                             ^

Comment: @RamNarayanan ...Which error? You didn't say what the error was.

Comment: Also, the carrot pointing to the error is under the semicolon.

Comment: @RamNarayanan Sounds like you may be missing either a bracket or a parenthesis when you copied the example over to your IDE. I recommend checking it carefully to make sure the methods and class are closed appropriately.